# VirtualBox NAT vs Bridged - accessibility of another host

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Windows 10 host with VirtualBox (5.0.10) Arch Linux guest.

Host's IP: `192.168.1.102`.
Guest's IP when in Bridged mode: `192.168.1.14`.
I also have another host (with a simple web server on port 80) in this network, let's call it X. It's IP: `192.168.1.10`.

When I configure guest's network adapter as NAT, I can access both host and X.
However, when I switch to Bridged mode, I can ping host from guest and vice-versa, but I cannot access X from the guest.

I imagined that when I set it to Bridged mode, it would behave as if it were just another machine on the network, with "equal rights" with another machine, such as X. However, this does not seem so.

What am I missing? What information can I add (I don't even know how to start analyzing the problem)?

**UPDATE**

I can ping and access X on port 80 with no problems from the host.

`ifconfig` in NAT mode:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::e883:bd15:fead:b72b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:e9:ff:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 349  bytes 273686 (267.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 208  bytes 16349 (15.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1f:38e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:1f:38:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27  bytes 2964 (2.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 648 (648.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ifconfig` in Bridged mode:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::e883:bd15:fead:b72b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:e9:ff:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6  bytes 1248 (1.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13  bytes 1948 (1.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1f:38e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:1f:38:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 578 (578.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I skipped the loopback device in both cases.
I guess it's `enp0s3` that's in question here - we can the IP change there - but I have honestly no idea what `enp0s8` might be, I'm quite sure I never configured it manually. When I was setting up DHCP service on guest, only `enp0s3` was there. So it must have been added when I started changing between NAT and Bridged? Would it make sense? In the beginning, it was set to NAT.

Comment: Can you please give the output of `ifconfig` if the guest is 'nix based, or `ipconfig` if it's Windows?

Comment: And please add that for both Bridged and NAT situations

Comment: Also, can your host ping X?

Answer (score -1):

If this output of ifconfig is the one of the guest, you obviously havn't configured enp0s3 for IP4 while in bridged mode but you have while in NAT mode. Try changing that.

Be blessed!